# Load dynamic data in Jquery Data Tables

Tags: jquery, datatables

```
 var tablerows = '';
var dataSet = [];
if (response.hasOwnProperty('records') && response.metadata.record_count > 0) {
    _.each(response.records, function (record) {
        var sku_data = get_api_data(urls.sku.list + "/" + record.skuid, api.access_token);

        if (sku_data != undefined) {
            sku_data.done(function (sku) {

                dataSet.push(sku.records[0].name);


                console.log(dataSet);
            })



        }

    })


    $('#demo').html('<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="display" id="example"></table>');

    $('#example').dataTable({
        "data": dataSet,
        "columns": [
            { "title": "Product" }
        ],
        "aoColumns": [
                null
        ]
    });
```

How do i dynamically add all the dataSet values to the Datatable.

Please help right now i am getting a blank array.

Comment: are you getting data in dataset? If yes, you need to initialize database once you receive data in dataset.

Comment: all the code is in a javascript function

Comment: Not using any database calls calling apis

Comment: what you get when you `console.log(dataSet)`

Comment: Oops... Sorry I wanted to say datatable and not database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not about jQuery DataTable, you need to use **promise** to solve your problem

```
    var tablerows = '';
    var dataSet = [];
    var dataSetPromise = [];
    if (response.hasOwnProperty('records') && response.metadata.record_count > 0) {
        _.each(response.records, function (record) {
            var sku_data = get_api_data(urls.sku.list + "/" + record.skuid, api.access_token);

            if (sku_data != undefined) {
                dataSetPromise.push(sku_data.done(function (sku) {

                    dataSet.push(sku.records[0].name);


                    console.log(dataSet);
                }));



            }

        })

    $.when.apply(null, dataSetPromise).done(function () {
        $('#demo').html('<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="display" id="example"></table>');

        $('#example').dataTable({
            "data": dataSet,
            "columns": [
                { "title": "Product" }
            ],
            "aoColumns": [
                    null
            ]
        });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Though i still get an empty table

Comment: what's the output of console.log(dataSet)

Comment: is sku_data a jquery Promise? just like the return value of $.get()

Comment: yes. It goes twice inside the $.when once the array has 0 values and once it has 35 values